# Question about performing k-fold CV with caret

Tags: cross-validation, model-comparison, caret

I have read the help manual of caret carefully: see A Short Introduction to the caret Package.

In its example, I found it split the data with createDataPartition before a model training.

```
library(caret)
library(mlbench)
data(Sonar)
set.seed(107)
inTrain <- creatDataPartition(y = Sonar$Class, p = .75, list = FALSE)
str(inTrain)
training <- Sonar[inTrain,]
testing <- Sonar[-inTrain,]
```

And does it make the repeated 10-fold CV with only the 75% data in the training set?

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", repeats = 3, classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)
plsFit <- train(Class~., data = training, method = "pls", tuneLength = 15, trControl = ctrl, metric = "ROC", preProc =  c("center", "scale"))
plsFit

plsClass <- predict(plsFit, newdata = testing)
```

So, I think a k-fold CV make the "k-1" data into the training set and "1" data into the testing set, and all sets of data should be put into the testing data set at least once?

The code above uses only the 75% data in the whole model training process and the 10-fold CV process, and the rest (25%) only in the last prediction process.
Do I understood these codes correctly?

I think the process in the caret manuals is different from the principal idea of k-fold CV, which really confused me.

And I want to perform 10-fold CV for model comparison, including rpart, adaboost, bagging, svm and kknn. Can the functions in caret make sense?
How can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

The first bit:

```
inTrain <- creatDataPartition(y = Sonar$Class, p = .75, list = FALSE)
```

splits the totality of your data into training (75%) and test (25%).

Usually, cross-validation and other resampling methods are used on the *training* set. So if you use `caret`'s `train` function for example and ask for 10-fold CV, the 10% held back is 10% of the training set.

> So, I think a k-fold CV make the "k-1" data into the training set and "1" data into the testing set,

Sort of (the terminology is getting in the way). During each iteration of 10 fold CV, 90% is used to fit the model and 10% is held out for prediction. Again, these are percentages of your training set.

> Can the functions in caret make sense?

You will have to clarify this part. `train` can fit [many different models](http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/modelList.html).

Comment: Thanks, you really help me a lot. And I still feel confuesd, why did it use the total data into the training set, so it can make k-fold CV for all of it and can make precidtion for the whole data. Or, only does the accuracy of prediction which is performed for hold out data will make sense?

Comment: @Archer, you split the data into `train` set (75%) and `test` set or called hold-out/back set (25%) as topepo said exactly. Finally, you should be able to optimize the model by using the `train` set only but that should be done via 10k-cv may be. so suppose you have 1000 whole data, 750 `train`, 250 `test`, tuning/optimization of model via e.g., 10-cv (very common approach) then you end up with 90% = 675 for fitting, the 10% = 75 for evaluation of the tuning parameters (specific to the model you choose). The best model finally evaluated on `test` = 250. Last thing fit model on data (10000).

Comment: while tuning via 10k-cv you include repetitions like 5 to 10, so totally you would do tuning on 50 to 100 data folds each fold is 90% of the `train` set, and evaluation (on the 10%) would be more stable by now since it would be built upon 50 to 100 samples. Final best model, is the winner out of these times.

Comment: @topepo: I still don't understand how \$results, \$bestTune, or \$finalModel contribute to $\hat y$ when I do predict.lm(). See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142386/explain-validation-process-of-repeated-k-fold-cross-validation# . I assume \$results is my i*k matrix of $\hat\beta_1...\hat\beta_p$ and $\hat {(RMSE/R^2)}_{validate}$, but ??